# Graph Database Object Relationship Diagram Tool

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I used to use a tool that would translate a text file into a diagram like this

[image]

But I don't remember the name of the tool - can someone remind me?

As an input it would take a text file that defined the objects and relationships and would export out an image file like the one above.  Note that this is not auto-generated from an existing database but from a text file that has the object and relationship definitions.

Comment: Are you referring to [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)?

Comment: Yes! That was it!  Is there a mac GUI that you would recommend - I tried downloading the pixelglow mac gui and it seems out of date since powerpc apps are no longer supported.

Comment: Great, I've added the answer to your question below - be sure to accept it.

Comment: I haven't used any GUIs myself, so can't make an informed recommendation. There is a selection of GUIs available on the [resources page of the GraphViz website](http://www.graphviz.org/content/resources), however. Maybe you can find something suitable there.

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/). This tool is used pretty extensively within the Neo4j ecosystem.